# Getting the path of URL data in intent

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent

I have the following activity:

```
package com.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class SplashActivity3 extends Activity
{
    Handler Handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity3.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            },
                1500);

        Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    }
}
```

If you see the last 3 lines, you can notice that they are created by Android Studio for handling App Links.

What I want to do is, get the complete URL that was clicked on to trigger the intent and pass it on to the WebViewActivity.class as a Bundle.

So, for example, if users have my app installed and they receive a URL of my app and they touch it, they will be asked if they want to open the URL in my app or browser. It's not a problem when it's just the homepage. But, if the users get a URL of some other page of my website, I want to load that page in my WebView. But, I want to show the splash screen before that. FOr that, I know I'll have to add that URL in a string using the putExtra in the intent, but, I don't know how to 'capture' the URL. Like, how to store the full URL in a string?

Comment: You are talking about deep links. Did you make any changes to the activity in your manifest. That activity needs an intent-filter

Comment: @DroiDev Yes. I have added the intent filter and it's working fine. Whenever a user taps on any link of my website, he/she gets an option to load the link in my app or the browser. My problem isn't limited to that. I need the open the exact link that was tapped on (for example, if someone taps on mydomain.tld/about.html, I want to load that 'about.html' page in a WebView). At present, no matter on what URL someone taps, the app always opens the default mydomain.tld/index.html page that's set in the MainActivity.html.

Comment: u need to get the URL that is coming into the app. You can do that by doing Intent intent = getIntent(); String url = intent.getStringData(); System.out.println(url); this should print the url coming into the app.... if it does, you can take that string, and full up your webview.

Comment: @DroiDev It seems, you still didn't get me. The part you've given me is for the receiving activity (i.e., the activity in which I want to open the link). I want the code for the activity that is going to give out the intent. I want to capture the URL in say Activity1 and then pass it on to Activity2. So, I need the code for Activity1.

Comment: So, you need to now how to pass data from one intent to another in native code?

Comment: @DroiDev My updated post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611882/capture-the-data-provided-by-intent. That's the best I can explain.