# Capture the data provided by Intent

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent, applinks

On this page: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking, in the

> 'Read data from incoming intents'

section, Google mentions:

> Once the system starts your activity through an intent filter, you can
>   use data provided by the Intent to determine what you need to render.
>   Call the getData() and getAction() methods to retrieve the data and
>   action associated with the incoming Intent.

And that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but, I'm unable to get help.

In this activity of mine:

```
package com.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class SplashActivity3 extends Activity
{
    Handler Handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash3);

        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity3.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            },
                1500);

        Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    }
}
```

I want to know (later tranfer it to another activity), the URL that was clicked on to open my app.

Basically, my app is using App Links (referred to as Deep Linking by some). So, in a case where a user 'A', sends user 'B' a link of a page on my website and B has my app installed, he/she will be able to open the link in my app instead of the browser.

As of now, B can open the link in my app, but, my app will always load the 'home page' (it's because I have coded my app to open the home page by default). I want to load the page that brought B in my app.

For a real life example, just like Facebook's app does. Suppose I share a link of a Facebook page or a profile to my friend. It's a standard HTTP link that's displayed in my web browser. Probably, I shared it with him on WhatsApp. He touches the link to open it. He has the official Facebook app installed on his phone. So, Android asks him if he wants to open the link in the Facebook app or in the browser. Now, when he chooses the browser, it's no problem at all. But, when he chooses the Facebook app, the app loads the profile or the page that exists on the link and not the home page of Facebook. That's what I want to achieve.

Please note, I'm talking about standard HTTP links here and not my app specific URIs.

UPDATE:

Here's something I tried now:

This is the same activity as above, I modified it like this:

```
package com.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class SplashActivity3 extends Activity
{
    Handler Handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        final String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();

        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("web", appLinkAction);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash3);

        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity3.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            },
                1500);


    }
}
```

And the activity in which I'm loading the URL:

```
package com.application;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView WebView;
    private ProgressBar ProgressBar;
    private LinearLayout LinearLayout;
    private String currentURL;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/eula.html");
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("customUA");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url3)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url3);
                return true;
            }
        });

        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean agreed = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("agreed",false);

        if(!agreed)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle_black_24dp)
                    .setTitle(R.string.eula_title)
                    .setView(wv)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                            editor.apply();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.decline, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView5);
        ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5);
        LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout5);

        ProgressBar.setMax(100);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String url = bundle.getString("web");

        WebView.loadUrl(R.string.url);
        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("customUA");
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                LinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                LinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                currentURL = url;
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webview, int i, String s, String s1)
            {
                WebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, ErrorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url2)
            {
                if (url2.contains("www.mydomain.tld"))
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url2);
                    return false;
                } else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url2));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
            {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                ProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.backward:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.forward:
                onForwardPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.refresh:
                WebView.reload();
                break;

            case R.id.share:
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,currentURL);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.shareWith)));
                break;

            case R.id.update:
                Intent intent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.about:

                WebView wv2 = new WebView(this);
                wv2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");
                wv2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv2.getSettings().setUserAgentString("customUA");
                wv2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url4)
                    {
                        view.loadUrl(url4);

                        return true;
                    }
                });

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp)
                        .setTitle(R.string.info)
                        .setView(wv2)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.okay, null)
                        .show();
                break;

            case R.id.exit:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialog)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                        .setTitle(R.string.title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.message)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                        .show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onForwardPressed()
    {
        if (WebView.canGoForward())
        {
            WebView.goForward();
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noFurther, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed ()
    {
        if (WebView.canGoBack())
        {
            WebView.goBack();
        } else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialog)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol url` error at `WebView.loadUrl(R.string.url);`

What to do?

Comment: What is the problem? Does `appLinkData` not contain the specific URL or have you problems to dissect the URL to find the desired activity and data to show?

Comment: @MichaelButscher In short, I don't know how to save the URL in a string. That part of code is auto generated by Android Studio. I don't know much of Java and so, I don't know what it's doing. I somehow want to tranfer that URL to a activity. As far as my understanding, I have to save that URL in a string in this activity and after that, I have to load the next activity and use the string there.

Comment: In this case you should start with [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), then the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/docs/).

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's what I'm referring to all this while. The other part of my app's ready. This is the last thing I need to implement.

Comment: There is [`Context.startActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) (an `Activity` is a `Context`). You may have to construct a proper `Intent` which is described in docs for `Intent`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher So, I guess, the auto-generated code already has the URL in it that I need?

Comment: The `Intent` you received has the URL as data, yes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for the help. Now, I just need to figure out how to construct the intent.

Comment: to pass data around with intent its intent.putExtra("key", "value"); Your value here would be the URL string. Then in the activity this intent goes to, you get the intent. Intent intent = getIntent(); String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");

Comment: @DroiDev Tried that. I still get the same error. Cannot resolve symbol.  And the `String value` part shows a warning variable value is never used even though I am using the R.string.value to load the WebView.

Comment: you dont use the R.string.value... you use value. i reread your question. you said you want a user to click a link, and that link takes them into the app to a specific page.... right? i talked to you about this in your other tread (stop creating threads). i am going to answer this with the way your question is asked.

Comment: @DroiDev Yeah, that solved it. Though the app's crashing. I'll investigate it. Thanks.